# Re-connect to SQL Server database after SQL Server 2014 reinstallation

Tags: sql-server, database, sql-server-2014

Please excuse my ignorance as I have not had to do this before.

The `C:` drive on our server failed yesterday (Microsoft Server 2012 R2) taking with it an installed instance of SQL Server 2014.

Luckily, our databases were stored on the `D:` drive. I have installed new `C:` drives, reinstalled Windows Server 2012 and I am currently in the process of reinstalling SQL Server 2014.

My question is: what is the best way to regain access to the databases on the `D:` drive and get back up and running?

Comment: If the database files are intact you should just be able to [reattach](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/attach-a-database?view=sql-server-ver16) them in the new SQL Server instance.  You'll likely need to reconnect db logins afteward.

Comment: This really doesn't have anything to do with **programming** (which *this site* is **all about**), but with DB administration - so it's off-topic here and belongs on [dba.stackexchange.com](http://dba.stackexchange.com) - voting to move.

Comment: @marc_s my apologies, I didn't know that this wouldn't be an appropriate question for here. I have often turned to the very kind (and knowledgeable) users of StackOverflow for help for SQL programming questions etc, and I didn't know "StackExchange" was the DB version of StackOverflow . Duly noted for future.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can Move databases Files "DatabaseName.mdf" & "DatabaseName_log.ldf"

to the new path and open sqlserver

then click right click on Databases then select Attach

and choose MDF file after click "OK" the Database will attached in Sqlserver

Comment: Do I have to move the files? Or can I attach them where they are currently stored on the D: drive?

Comment: you can attach it from anywhere .